# jquery select element above after they are created

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have "read more" button, once pressed it loads 10 posts. Every post has bottom border. When that button is pressed and 10 new posts are loaded, I want to remove that border for last element (first above "read more" button).

Code structure:

```
<div class="container">
  <article class="col-md-12">1 lorem ipsum dolorem</article>
  <article class="col-md-12">2 lorem ipsum dolorem</article>
  <article class="col-md-12">3 lorem ipsum dolorem</article>
  <article class="col-md-12">4 lorem ipsum dolorem</article>
  <article class="col-md-12">5 lorem ipsum dolorem</article>
  <article class="col-md-12">6 lorem ipsum dolorem</article>
  <article class="col-md-12">7 lorem ipsum dolorem</article>
  <article class="col-md-12">8 lorem ipsum dolorem</article>
  <article class="col-md-12">9 lorem ipsum dolorem</article>
  <article class="col-md-12">10 lorem ipsum dolorem</article>
  <button id="read-more">Read more</button>
</div>
```

jquery:

```
$(function() {
   $('#read-more').on('click', function(e) {
      $('#read-more').closest().css("border-bottom", "none");
   });
});
```

How can this be solved?

Thanks.

Comment: can you post the css which you are using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

```
$(function() {
   $('#read-more').on('click', function(e) {
      $('#read-more').prev().css("border-bottom-width", "0px");
   });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

you don't need to use javascript for this, you can use css alone if you wish:

```
.container article:last-of-type{
    border-bottom: none;
}
```